# Is it possible to filter list of Ruby money currencies to only active ones?

Tags: ruby, currency, money-rails

I'm using the [money gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) for currency conversions in a Rails app and need to generate a list of currencies for a form select tag.

The suggested documentation relies on getting calling `Money::Currency.table` to get a list of all currencies but this includes non iso currencies (e.g. Bitcoin) and old currencies (e.g. three invalid Zimbabwean Dollar entries).

Is there a way to only get a list of valid ISO currency codes without maintaining my own list?

Comment: https://www.currency-iso.org/dam/downloads/lists/list_one.xml

Comment: When asking "Is there a way", your question instantly becomes very broad unless you show what you tried and narrow the scope of the query. "Is there a way...?" "Yes" doesn't help anyone. "I tried this and this and they didn't work" narrows the question and allows us to not guess what you're really asking. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, "[mcve]" and its linked page, and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)" which will help explain why we need more detail and the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The money gem does include [separate lists](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/blob/v6.8.2/config), but unfortunately, they are [merged together](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/blob/v6.8.2/lib/money/currency/loader.rb#L9-L13):

```
def load_currencies
  currencies = parse_currency_file("currency_iso.json")
  currencies.merge! parse_currency_file("currency_non_iso.json")
  currencies.merge! parse_currency_file("currency_backwards_compatible.json")
end
```

You could invoke that code manually to obtain just the `currency_iso.json` list:

```
Money::Currency.send(:parse_currency_file, 'currency_iso.json')
#=> {
#   :aed=>{:priority=>100, :iso_code=>"AED", :name=>"United Arab Emirates Dirham", :symbol=>"د.إ", :alternate_symbols=>["DH", "Dhs"], :subunit=>"Fils", :subunit_to_unit=>100, :symbol_first=>true, :html_entity=>"", :decimal_mark=>".", :thousands_separator=>",", :iso_numeric=>"784", :smallest_denomination=>25},
#   :afn=>{:priority=>100, :iso_code=>"AFN", :name=>"Afghan Afghani", :symbol=>"؋", :alternate_symbols=>["Af", "Afs"], :subunit=>"Pul", :subunit_to_unit=>100, :symbol_first=>false, :html_entity=>"", :decimal_mark=>".", :thousands_separator=>",", :iso_numeric=>"971", :smallest_denomination=>100},
#   :all=>{:priority=>100, :iso_code=>"ALL", :name=>"Albanian Lek", :symbol=>"L", :disambiguate_symbol=>"Lek", :alternate_symbols=>["Lek"], :subunit=>"Qintar", :subunit_to_unit=>100, :symbol_first=>false, :html_entity=>"", :decimal_mark=>".", :thousands_separator=>",", :iso_numeric=>"008", :smallest_denomination=>100},
#   ...
#   :zar=>{:priority=>100, :iso_code=>"ZAR", :name=>"South African Rand", :symbol=>"R", :alternate_symbols=>[], :subunit=>"Cent", :subunit_to_unit=>100, :symbol_first=>true, :html_entity=>"&#x0052;", :decimal_mark=>".", :thousands_separator=>",", :iso_numeric=>"710", :smallest_denomination=>10},
#   :zmk=>{:priority=>100, :iso_code=>"ZMK", :name=>"Zambian Kwacha", :symbol=>"ZK", :disambiguate_symbol=>"ZMK", :alternate_symbols=>[], :subunit=>"Ngwee", :subunit_to_unit=>100, :symbol_first=>false, :html_entity=>"", :decimal_mark=>".", :thousands_separator=>",", :iso_numeric=>"894", :smallest_denomination=>5},
#   :zmw=>{:priority=>100, :iso_code=>"ZMW", :name=>"Zambian Kwacha", :symbol=>"ZK", :disambiguate_symbol=>"ZMW", :alternate_symbols=>[], :subunit=>"Ngwee", :subunit_to_unit=>100, :symbol_first=>false, :html_entity=>"", :decimal_mark=>".", :thousands_separator=>",", :iso_numeric=>"967", :smallest_denomination=>5}}
# }
```

Note however that this is a private method so it might change in future versions.